# xcode dropdown - shows all my class properties and methods. Just want methods

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

Not sure what to call it, but in xcode there is a dropdown that lists
all the properties and methods in the current file.

Is there a way to just show the methods?  I have a few classes with a boatload of properties, and having to scroll past them in the dropdown is a pain.

Thanks!

Comment: why not just start typing the method names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You cant hide your properties from the drop down list. It is for showing methods and properties both. so if you think you take more time to find the method then type one or two letter : list will be automatically sort.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :(

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Plugin for hiding properties in dropdown list https://github.com/shpakovski/Xprop